# What ways can languages parse sub-clauses from the rest of a clause?

Tags: syntax, relative-clauses

I only know of two strategies. Most European languages, like English, rely mainly intonation to keep the arguments in a sub-clause, particularly center-embedded clauses, from being accidentally to be assumed to be part of the main clause. German seems to be the only exception. All sub-clauses are SOV, so the beginning of all sub-clauses is marked with a relativizer, as expected, but the end is marked with an inflected verb. This means there's no upper limit to how elaborate a sub-clause can get in German.

I want to know other strategies used by other languages, assuming there are any. I've found that with many things, there's only a finite number of ways to do them. There's only so many possible noun phrase orders, same thing with word order. There's only about half a dozen alignments. A few hundred phones all languages can make use of. You get the idea.

Are the two I listed the only two possible strategies or are there alternatives? I feel its euro-centric to put this into a conlang, but I know of no other way.

Comment: Please give some concrete examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hittite marks the beginning of each clause, and doesn't allow any nesting: you have to chain them together instead of putting one inside another.

For example, to say "send back my subjects that you've taken and led away":

> ÌR.MEŠ=*YA*=*wa=z ku-ēs dā-s*
> subjects=my=QUOT=INT which-N.PL take-2S.PST
> "My subjects that you have taken,
>
> *nu=war=as=kan kattanta pehute-t*
> CLAUSE=QUOT=3P.ACC=MOD away lead-2S.PST
> you have led them away,
>
> *nu=war=as=mu arha upp-i*
> CLAUSE=QUOT=3P.ACC=1S.DAT back send-IMP.SG
> send them back to me!"

The *nu* particle, known as a "sentence connective", doesn't really have any meaning of its own but introduces a new clause when there isn't something else filling that role. (In the first clause, a noun is moved to the beginning for emphasis, so *nu* isn't needed—the fact that all the clitics stack onto it indicates that it's the start of the clause.)

Certain markers, like *=war* to indicate a quotation, are also repeated on each new clause head.

Comment: So, it forbids center-embedding basically?

Comment: @user8600 Indeed; no recursing clauses, just iterate and use pointers back to previous clauses as needed

Comment: I have heard of languages that forbid center-embedding. How common is this though? I tried to check on wals, but they don't have this listed as a 'feature' as best as I can tell. Neither the words 'embed' or 'center' turn up anything. Nothing really relevant comes up if I search 'clause', though it did list something about 'double-headed clauses', but I can't find anywhere what that means.

Comment: @user8600 I'm afraid I don't know off the top of my head. Hittite is the one language I know that does this.

Answer (score 2):

**Japanese** allows relative clauses:

- Generally each clause has *NOUN1 PARTICLE1 NOUN2 PARTICLE2 NOUN3 PARTICLE3 ... VERB* format. Subject is optional and can be skipped if it can be guessed from context (which often happens when it is "I", or "thou" for questions). *VERB* can be verb or adjective.
- Relative clause is created by putting *VERB* before given *NOUN*. Any particle, which specified function of *NOUN*, disappears, causing potentially ambiguous meaning. E.g. *VERB NOUN*. <sub>(Particle *ga* is used to mark subject in declarative main clauses only since late Late Middle Japanese (according to Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 366-368)).)</sub>
- No relative pronouns.
- No particles or other words mark beginning or end of relative clause.
- *VERB* in relative clause should be in Attributive form (連体形), but anyway in modern Japanese, Attributive form (連体形) is identical to Terminal/Conclusive form (終止形) for all verbs except copula *na* / *da*. <sub>(In Western Old Japanese and Early Middle Japanese, Attributive form and  Terminal/Conclusive form were different for adjectives, vowel-stem verbs and few irregular verbs, but not for regular consonant-stem verbs, which comprise majority of verbs. Traces of distinction for consonant-stem verbs exist in [Eastern Old Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Dialects).)</sub>

---

Examples:

> OJ: *ki taka**si***
>
> NJ: *ki ga taka**i***
>
> "tree is tall"

> OJ: *[taka**ki**] ki*
>
> NJ: *[taka**i**] ki*
>
> "tree [which is tall]" / "[tall] tree"

> OJ: *ware [taka**ki**] ki wo mi*
>
> NJ: *watasi ga [taka**i**] ki wo miru*
>
> "I see tree [which is tall]" / "I see [tall] tree"

> OJ: *ki takaku ari**ki***
>
> EMJ: *ki takakari**ki***
>
> NJ: *ki ga takakatta*
>
> "tree was tall"

> OJ: *[takaku ari**si**] ki*
>
> EMJ: *[takakari**si**] ki*
>
> NJ: *[takakatta] ki*
>
> "tree [which was tall]"

> OJ: *uwo kupu*
>
> NJ: *sakana ga taberu* / *uo ga taberu*
>
> "fish eats (somebody/something)"

> OJ: *uwo wo kupu*
>
> NJ: *sakana wo taberu* / *uo wo taberu*
>
> "(somebody/something) eats fish"

> OJ: *[kupu] uwo*
>
> NJ: *[taberu] sakana* / *[taberu] uo*
>
> "fish [who eats (somebody/something)]" or "fish [whom (somebody/something) eats]"

> LMJ: *ɸana kirei **nari***
>
> NJ: *hana ga kirei **da***
>
> "flower is pretty"

> LMJ: *[kirei **naru**] ɸana*
>
> NJ: *[kirei **na**] hana*
>
> "flower [which is pretty]"

> LMJ: *ware [kirei **naru**] ɸana wo miru*
>
> NJ: *watasi ga [kirei **na**] hana wo miru*
>
> "I see flower [which is pretty]"

> NJ: *watasi wa [[umi de oyoide iru] hito wo tabete iru] same wo mite iru*
>
> "I see shark [who is eating human [who is swimming in sea]]"
>
> (Example of sentence with relative clause inside relative clause)

> NJ: *kore wa [watasi ga anata kara karita] hon da*
>
> "this is book [which I borrowed from thee]"

**[ ]** are used to mark relative clauses.

Explanation of particles used in above examples:

*ga* - Subject

*wo* - Direct object

*de* - Location

*kara* - Source ("from")

OJ *pa* / NJ *wa* - Topic

---

(Formal copula *de aru* in modern language has identical Terminal/Conclusive form and Attributive form. *da* developed as contraction of *de aru* and is used only in terminal function in modern language. *na* developed as contraction of older copula *naru* and is used only in attributive function in modern language. But when *na* and *da* initially developed, they were used in both functions.)

---

**Korean** has some [similarities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_verbs#Attributive_endings) (at least in using Attributive forms of verbs placed before nouns and lack of relative pronouns).

Comment: Funny enough, I saw a Japanese speaker demonstrate once how Japanese does allow center-embedded clauses. The only noun phrase part of the main clause that preceeded the embedded clause was marked with the topic marker wa/ha. He claimed it was obvious to him that the first noun phrase was part of the main clause and not the embedded clause, but when I asked how he could determine that he admitted he didn't know, he just knew that was the right way to interpret it. Based on your answer, maybe it was simply the fact that it was a topic, which is often also the subject/agent?

Comment: @user8600 Topic particle は is not used inside relative clauses (but は can be found there in different functions), so *NOUN+は* can be generally assumed to be part of main clause.

Comment: So, going back to your original post. Japanese basically only allows 'simple' relative clauses. Pronouns, subjects, and topics can only ever be part of the main clause, among perhaps other things? I have heard that English allows far more complex relative clauses than you would normally see, but honestly I've never seen someone state what English allows that other languages do not. German does allow everything English would, plus more. As I said, there's not really a limit to how complex a relative clause can be in German.

Comment: @user8600 Japanese does not have relative pronouns, but has personal pronouns and demonstrative pronouns, and they can be placed inside relative clauses without problems. Case particles (including subject particle *ga*) can be placed inside relative clauses. I added more examples.

Comment: Also for clarity, topic particle belongs to binding particles ([係助詞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/係助詞)), not case particles ([格助詞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/格助詞)). There are also several other types of [particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles) ([助詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/助詞)).

Comment: “Any particle, which specified function of NOUN, disappears, causing potentially ambiguous meaning. E.g. VERB NOUN.” — This could be clearer. At first read, I thought you meant that any particle that shows the function of NOUN in the _main_ clause disappears (which of course it doesn’t, e.g., _taberu sakana **wo** mita_). It wasn’t until I read the fish-eating/eating fish example that I realised you’re talking about any particle that specifies NOUN’s function _in the relative clause_. // “VERB in relative clause should be in Attributive form (連体形)” — Or perfective/past (_takakatta ki_)!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet About Attributive form, I mean Attributive form for given combination of tense, voice, aspect etc. Modern *-ta* suffix for Perfective / Past tense has the same forms *-ta* for its Conclusive form and *-ta* for its Attributive form, but ancestor of this suffix, which was possibly rather Stative in Early Middle Japanese, had forms *-tari* for its Conclusive form and *-taru* for its Attributive form. These *-tari* and *-taru* are contractions of *-te ari* and *-te aru*, from *-te* form (still used in modern language) and verb *ari* / *aru* (modern *aru*).

Comment: @Arfrever I figured that’s what you meant, but when you look at (most) descriptions of the Modern Japanese verb, only the -る form is called attributive/連体形, with the -た form being just called ‘past’ or ‘perfective’, so someone only familiar with modern descriptions would likely not think of the -た form as being attributive or conclusive, just past.